# ProgressDialog - Dialog not showing

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm new to `Progress Dialog`. I created a `class DBOperations extends AsyncTask` and implemented `methods onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute`. I made DB calls like

```
 newDBOperations().execute( ... );
```

The `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` methods invoked perfectly, but i was not able to see the `Progress Dialog` on my emulator

Code look like

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setMessage("Please Wait ...");
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
    if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Should i use `newHandler().postDelayed` ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: DB operations means a call to web api??

Comment: I forget (and the docs aren't saying): does `ProgressDialog` have a `Builder` nested class? If so, that's what you need to do

Comment: `@sJy ` I use `PHP` to contact with `MYSQL` and get records. I use `DBOperations` to get data from `PHP`

Comment: `@Jeeter` I'm new to `Progress Dialog` and i don't know about `Builder`

Comment: What's your `context` variable? You should use `MainActivity.this` (or whatever your activity is called)

Comment: Did you initialized your `context` variable correctly?
Could you please try with set Progress Dialog Style? Like `dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);`

Comment: Also your `onPostExecute` method will not dismiss the Progress Dialog. As you created local instance of that dialog.

Comment: @NimmagaddaGowtham did any of the answers work for you?

Comment: `@MdSufiKhan` No problem in passing the `Context`. I did that correctly. I used `dialog.setProgressStyle()` as you suggested but no use

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it. Works good for me.

**Main Activity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
DBOperations task;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); // declared in xml
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // starts AsyncTask on button click
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            task = new DBOperations(MainActivity.this); // pass the context to the constructor
            task.execute();
        }
    });
}
```

}

And **DBOperations.java**

```
public class DBOperations extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

Context ctx;
ProgressDialog dialog; // should be declared outside onPreExecute

public DBOperations(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setMessage("Please Wait ...");
    dialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000); // waits 3 seconds
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.dismiss();
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
}
```

}

Hope this helps :)

Comment: `@Artur` The difference between your answer my code is calling `super` methods(`onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()`). I tried that also but no use

Answer (score 0):

I put this code into an isolated application, and it showed the dialog:

```
 ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
 dialog.setCancelable(false);
 dialog.setMessage("Please Wait ...");
 dialog.show();
```

It's the exact same code you use, except I replaced your `context` variable with `MainActivity.this`

So I believe the `context` variable you are using is an issue. Make sure you're using the correct `Context`.

---

Also, as @MdSufiKhan pointed out in the comments, you won't be able to dismiss it properly, since you create it locally in `onPreExecute()`. Leave it as a field of `DBOperations`

Comment: `@Jeeter` I passed `MainActivity.this` from `MainActivity` to `service layer` and then to `DAO layer` and then to `DBOperations`. In `DBOperations` I used the above code you suggested in your answer but no use

Comment: I created the `dialog object` at `class level` and initialzed in `onPreExecute()` and closed at `onPostExecute()` still the problem exists